# Load/Save .ini file

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I wrote a code that let's me save variables to a .ini file with a custom filename. The filename depends on the text in EditBox1. No problem there. My issue is how do I load those variables from that custom filename by selecting the file from a load file window (windows explorer).

```
DataIni:=TIniFile.Create(getcurrentdir+'\save folder\' + EditBox1.Text +'.ini');
```

Sample save variable

```
DataIni.WriteString('INFO','FirstName',EditFirstName.Text);
DataIni.WriteString('INFO','MiddleName',EditMiddleName.Text);
DataIni.WriteString('INFO','FamilyName',EditFamilyName.Text);
```

Sample load variable

```
EditFirstName.Text := DataIni.ReadString('INFO','FirstName',EditFirstName.Text);
EditMiddleName.Text := DataIni.ReadString('INFO','MiddleName',EditMiddleName.Text);
EditFamilyName.Text := DataIni.ReadString('INFO','FamilyName',EditFamilyName.Text);
```

So for example the EditBox1.Text = 'MyFile1', how do I load the variables saved in MyFile1.ini by selecting MyFile1.ini from a list of other files?

Comment: Use `TOpenDialog`. Also, `TMemIniFile` is preferred to `TIniFile`, because the latter uses deprecated Windows APIs. And you should not rely on the working directory being defined. It could be pretty much anything.

Comment: "Deprecated api" - GetPrivateProfileStrings? This API is used many applications, including Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TOpenDialog` to get the name of the file that you want, so you call a function to load your values.

```
uses IniFiles;
...
```

On click the button, call a OpenDialog.Execute to allows to select a file name.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TOpenDialog.Create(Self) do
  try
    Filter := 'Ini Files (*.ini)|*.ini';
    if Execute then
      LoadMyVars(FileName);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

This function load the values of your ini file to the controls.

```
procedure TForm1.LoadMyVars(const AFileName: string);
var
  DataIni : TIniFile;
begin
  DataIni := TIniFile.Create(AFileName);
  try
    EditFirstName.Text := DataIni.ReadString('INFO','FirstName', '');
    EditMiddleName.Text := DataIni.ReadString('INFO','MiddleName', '');
    EditFamilyName.Text := DataIni.ReadString('INFO','FamilyName', '');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(DataIni);
  end;
end;
```